# Executing code on a schedule, and skipping a task

Tags: c#

## Definition

It is necessary to run the code for example in 12:00, 15:00, 19:00, 20:00 every day.

The task that is being performed can be any, for example, copying a folder.

## My implementation

There is a code for running tasks on a schedule:

```cs
public class TaskScheduler
    {
        private static TaskScheduler _instance;
        private List<Timer> _timers = new List<Timer>();
        private TaskScheduler() { }
        
        public static TaskScheduler Instance => _instance ?? (_instance = new TaskScheduler());
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Create new Task
        /// </summary>
        /// <code>
        /// TaskScheduler.Instance.ScheduleTask(
        /// ()=>
        /// {
        /// 
        /// }, new TimeSpan(0, 20, 0));
        ///
        /// TaskScheduler.Instance.ScheduleTask(Action, TimeSpan);
        /// 
        /// </code>
        /// <param name="task">Action</param>
        /// <param name="time"></param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="OverflowException"></exception>
        public void ScheduleTask(Action task, TimeSpan time)
        {
            ScheduleTask(task, time.Hours, time.Minutes, time.Seconds);
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Create new Task
        /// </summary>
        /// <code>
        /// TaskScheduler.Instance.ScheduleTask(
        /// ()=>
        /// {
        /// 
        /// }, 1, 20, 0);
        ///
        /// TaskScheduler.Instance.ScheduleTask(Action, hour, minute, second);
        /// 
        /// </code>
        /// <param name="task">Action</param>
        /// <param name="hour">Hour</param>
        /// <param name="min">Minute</param>
        /// <param name="second">Second</param>
        /// <param name="intervalInHour">Interval in hours</param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="OverflowException"></exception>
        public void ScheduleTask(Action task, int hour = 0, int min = 0, int second = 1,  double intervalInHour = 24d)
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var firstRun = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, hour, min, second);

            if (now > firstRun) firstRun = firstRun.AddDays(1);
           
            var timeToGo = firstRun - now;

            if (timeToGo <= TimeSpan.Zero) timeToGo = TimeSpan.Zero;
         
            var timer = new Timer(x =>
            {
                task.Invoke();
            }, null, timeToGo, TimeSpan.FromHours(intervalInHour));

            _timers.Add(timer);
        }
    }
```

It works great, tasks are running, working.

There is a certain nuance, there is a code that copies a directory to a directory.

```cs
public static class FolderCopper
    {
        public static void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target, CancellationToken token)
        {
            if (!source.Exists) return;
            if (!target.Exists) target.Create();

            var po = new ParallelOptions
            {
                CancellationToken = token
            };

            Parallel.ForEach(source.GetDirectories(), po, (sourceChildDirectory) => 
            {
                if (po.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    po.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }
                CopyAll(sourceChildDirectory, new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, sourceChildDirectory.Name)), token);
            });

            Parallel.ForEach(source.GetFiles(), po, sourceFile =>
            {
                if (po.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    po.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }
                var file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, sourceFile.Name));
                switch (file.Exists)
                {
                    case false:
                        sourceFile.CopyTo(file.FullName);
                        break;
                    case true when file.LastWriteTimeUtc < sourceFile.LastWriteTimeUtc:
                        sourceFile.CopyTo(file.FullName, true);
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

It must be run for example once every 20 or 10 minutes.

I call in this way:

````cs
Utils.Task Scheduler.Instance.Schedule Task(() => {}, 0, 20, 0, 0.33); //Task, hours, minutes, seconds, the interval in hours of 20 minutes is 0.33.
```c#
Or:

```c#
Utils.Task Scheduler.Instance.Schedule Task(() => {//coppy}, 1, 20, 30, 24); //Task, hours, minutes, seconds, the interval in hours.
````

One and the same task is always started.

Consider the situation, running the code at 12:00 and 13: 00 to copy the directory. The directory weighs 1670 GB. Accordingly, he does not have time to copy copy, and starts another 1 task.

### Question

How can I rewrite the code so that it does not run another 1 instance if the previous one did not work, and just skip the task?

Comment: In general, there is nothing wrong, with trying to implement such a functionality yourself. However, unless you're doing that for learning or other explanatory purposes, you might be better off, using an existing solution (like [HangfireIO](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Cronos) or [Quarz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)). There are quite a number of issues you have to handle to make things reliable (for example the one you have here - "overlapping timer events"). Just a thought.

Comment: @Christian.K This is a good option, but I don't like how the mechanism is implemented in these libraries. And plus, it's better to write it yourself, so that you can then play and change something.

Comment: All of the major operating systems have built-in mechanisms for doing this.  Task Scheduler for Windows, cron for Linux and MacOS.

Comment: Drop the `void ScheduleTask(Action task, int hour = 0, int min = 0, int second = 1,  double intervalInHour = 24d)` overload. The one with `TimeSpan` is sufficient.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have already changed it to the option below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it through the blocking mechanism.

Described the class for the work of the task itself:

```cs
public class TimedTask
    {
        private Timer _timer;
        private readonly Action _actionToInvoke;
        private TimeSpan _intervalTime;
        private TimeSpan _startTime;

        private const int WAITING_TIME_IN_MINUTES = 1;

        private object _locker = new object();

        public TimedTask(Action toInvoke, TimeSpan startTime, TimeSpan interval)
        {
            this._actionToInvoke = toInvoke;
            this._startTime = startTime;
            this._intervalTime = interval;
        }
        public void Start()
        {
            this.Stop();
            TimeSpan timeToGo = CalculateTheFirstStartTime();
            _timer = new Timer(Callback, null, timeToGo, _intervalTime);
        }
        public void Stop()
        {
            var local = _timer;
            _timer = null;
            local?.Dispose();
        }

        private TimeSpan CalculateTheFirstStartTime()
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var firstRun = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, _startTime.Hours, _startTime.Minutes, _startTime.Seconds);
            if (now > firstRun) firstRun = firstRun.AddDays(1);
            var timeToGo = firstRun - now;
            if (timeToGo <= TimeSpan.Zero) timeToGo = TimeSpan.Zero;
            return timeToGo;
        }

        private void Callback(object state)
        {
            var timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(WAITING_TIME_IN_MINUTES);

            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} Попытка запуска");
            if (Monitor.TryEnter(_locker, timeout))
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} Попытка успешна");
                    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} Запускаю задачу");
                    this._actionToInvoke();
                    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} Задача выполнена");

                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(_locker);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} Запуск не осуществлён");
            }
        }
    }
```

And a class that is a collection of tasks:

```cs
public class Scheduler
    {
        private List<TimedTask> _tasks = new List<TimedTask>();
        public void ScheduleJob(Action action, TimeSpan firstRun)
        {
            ScheduleJob(action, firstRun, new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0));
        }

        public void ScheduleJob(Action action, TimeSpan firstRun, TimeSpan interval)
        {
            var task = new TimedTask(action, firstRun, interval);
            _tasks.Add(task);
            task.Start();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _tasks.ForEach(t => t.Stop());
            _tasks.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a variable (like a static bool) to save the state. Ensure only locked access is possible and query that. If state is still running, then return, else do your work.

```
class Foo {
  private        bool   Running    = false;
  private static object lockObject = new object();

  public void Run() {
    lock (lockObject) {
      if (Running) return;

      Running = true;
    }

    try {
      // do your stuff
    } finally {
      lock (lockObject) {
        Running = false;
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Above is simplified code to demonstrate the idea

Comment: This is a terrible idea to use a `static` lock object. What if there are a million instances of `Foo`?

Comment: I also get the idea where you're going with this, but you're expecting the OP to have a leap of intuition to know what to do next. How would you use this technique in the OP's code that solves the issue?